# Unable to load 25GB dataset in PySpark local mode with 56GB RAM free

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, heap-memory

***I am having trouble loading and processing a 25GB Parquet dataset (of stackoverflow.com posts) on a single beefy machine in local mode with 12 cores/64GB of RAM.***

I have more memory on my machine that is free and allocated to `pyspark` than the size of a Parquet dataset (let alone two columns of the dataset), and yet I am unable to run any operations on the DataFrame once I load it. This is confusing, and I can't figure out what to do.

Specifically, I have a Parquet dataset that is 25GB:

```
$ du -sh data/stackoverflow/parquet/Posts.df.parquet

25G data/stackoverflow/parquet/Posts.df.parquet
```

I have a machine with 56GB of free RAM:

```
$ free -h

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   
available
Mem:            62G        4.7G         56G         23M        1.7G         
57G
Swap:           63G          0B         63G
```

I have configured PySpark to use 50GB of RAM (have tried adusting maxResultSize to no effect).

My configuration looks like this:

```
$ cat ~/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

spark.io.compression.codec org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec
spark.driver.memory 50g
spark.jars ...
spark.executor.cores 12
spark.driver.maxResultSize 20g
```

My environment looks like this:

```
$ cat ~/spark/conf/spark-env.sh

PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/nvm/spark/work
SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/nvm/spark/local
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=50g
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=12
```

I load the data like this:

```
$ pyspark

>>> posts = spark.read.parquet('data/stackoverflow/parquet/Posts.df.parquet')
```

It loads ok, but any operation - including if I run a `limit(10)` on the DataFrame first - results in an out of heap space error.

```
>>> posts.limit(10)\
    .select('_ParentId','_Body')\
    .filter(posts._ParentId == 9915705)\
    .show()

[Stage 1:>                                                       (0 + 12) / 195]19/06/30 17:26:13 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 7.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
19/06/30 17:26:13 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
19/06/30 17:26:13 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
at org.apache.parquet.bytes.HeapByteBufferAllocator.allocate(HeapByteBufferAllocator.java:32)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutiveChunkList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:1166)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:805)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:301)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:256)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:159)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/06/30 17:26:13 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 10.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 11)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
    at org.apache.parquet.bytes.HeapByteBufferAllocator.allocate(HeapByteBufferAllocator.java:32)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutiveChunkList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:1166)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:805)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/06/30 17:26:13 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 6.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
19/06/30 17:26:13 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 7,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
19/06/30 17:26:13 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 11,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
...
```

The following will run, suggesting the problem is the `_Body` field (obviously the largest):

```
>>> posts.limit(10).select('_Id').show()

+---+
|_Id|
+---+
|  4|
|  6|
|  7|
|  9|
| 11|
| 12|
| 13|
| 14|
| 16|
| 17|
+---+
```

**What am I to do?** I could use EMR, but I would like to be able to load this dataset locally and that seems an entirely reasonable thing to be able to do in this situation.

Comment: you data set in memory will consume a lot more than your serialized data. every single object created in java will add _at least_ 12 bytes for two headers it has, then there is _padding_, then there is space that is lost between fields sometimes, _then_... and so on. not to speak of the serialization itself that was used (I have no idea which); but take `HashMap` and plain java serialization for one example - once deserialized - it will be a _huge_ difference.

Comment: Hi @rjurney how many executors do you have?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis This is a good question. I have 12 - one for each hyperthread core. Is the executor/worker memory setting overall or per worker? If it is per worker - there is my problem :) I need to divide by 12.

Answer (score 1):

The default memory fraction for Spark's storage and computation is `0.6`. Under your config it will be `0.6 * 50GB = 30GB`. But the  representation of data in memory may consume more space than the serialized disk version.

Please check the section of [Memory Management](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management) to get more details.

Comment: Thanks, I will try playing with this as it seems the memory fraction could go higher than 0.6.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the spark memory config while running the pyspark command:

```
pyspark --conf spark.driver.memory=50g --conf spark.executor.pyspark.memory=50g
```

Check this [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) for the config to set.

You might also need to figure out the number of executors you need based on your hardware.

Comment: These are already set in both `spark-defaults.conf` and `spark-env.sh`. The executor count is set to 12, one for each hyperthreading core.